# Editing a local storage item twice is returning an undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am creating a to do list and everything seems to be working well. I am able to create, delete and edit items. However, if I try to edit an item twice - it returns a undefined.

Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/willwebdesigner/786Qu/17/

```
// Edit a task
$(document).on("click", "#tasks li a.edit", function() {

    var thisID = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    $(this).parent().html("<form><input class='taskEdit" + thisID + "' value=''><input type='submit' value='Edit me'></form>")
    .submit(function() {
         localStorage.setItem(thisID, $(".taskEdit" + thisID ).val());
        $(this).html(localStorage.getItem(thisID) + menuButtons);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are changing the `innerHTML` when you're unloading the page? The submit does not get prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is submitting, reloading the page before the value can be stored in local storage, and once the page reloads and tries to get that value from local storage, it's undefined.

Why exactly do you submit a form and reload the page every time a value is stored in local storage ?

And the submit function is bound to `$(this).parent()`, not the form which contain the "Edit me" button.

```
$(document).on("click", "#tasks li a.edit", function () {
    var thisID = $(this).parent().attr("id"),
        form = $("<form><input class='taskEdit" + thisID + "' value=''><input type='submit' value='Edit me'></form>");

    $(this).parent().empty().append(form);
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem(thisID, $(".taskEdit" + thisID).val());
        $(this).html(localStorage.getItem(thisID) + menuButtons);
    });
});
```

[**FIXED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/786Qu/18/)

Comment: He does not submit the form on storing. He stores the form value on submitting the form which is created on clicking an edit link.

Comment: @Bergi - the appended form clearly submits for me when the submit button is clicked (Edit me), reloading the page, and retrieving an undefined value from local storage ?

Comment: Thanks adeneo, that seems to have done the trick. I'm going to just review your code to learn and take in what you changed. Bergi - that was my intention. I wasn't actually submitting a form I was just taking the value from it and setting it in local storage.

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, true. Your wording sounded like "JS submits the form when a value is stored in local storage", though I might have misunderstood this.

Comment: actually form was not being submitted there, but the event 'submit' was delegated more than once..

Answer (score 0):

I have amended your code slightly as the new value was getting stored inside a form and causing a browser crash when deleting items.

```
$(document).on("click", "#tasks li a.edit", function () {
    var thisID = $(this).parent().attr("id"),
        form = $("<form class='editForm'><input class='taskEdit" + thisID + "'   value=''><input type='submit' value='Edit me'></form>");

    $(this).parent().empty().append(form);
    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem(thisID, $(".taskEdit" + thisID).val());
        $(this).parent().html(localStorage.getItem(thisID) + menuButtons);
        $(this).remove('.editForm');
    });
});
```